# Finding the diameter of a circle that is against an edge

Tags: geometry, puzzle

> There's a circle of diameter $d$ that is on a wall, and touches a block. Find the value of $d$.

I'm really unsure how to go about solving this. I wanted to first approach this by using the arc length, but I'm really unsure how to proceed. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If appears that the circle is touching a surface to its left and another surface below it.

If we were to graph this circle with these two surfaces representing the $x$ and $y$ axes, the circle would have the equation

$$(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$

in order for it to just touch either surface.

If the circle also just touches the block that is $5$ units wide and $8$ units long, the point $(5,8)$ must be on the circle. If we plug this value into the equation, we get

$$(5-r)^2+(8-r)^2=r^2$$

$$25-10r+r^2+64-16r+r^2=r^2$$

$$r^2-26r+89=0$$

If we use the quadratic formula, we get solutions of

$$r=13\pm4\sqrt{5}$$

One of these solutions, $13-4\sqrt{5}$, doesn't work, though, because the radius becomes too small to leave enough room in the bottom left corner for the block.

This means that

$$r=13+4\sqrt{5}$$

which consequently means

$$d=2r=2(13+4\sqrt{5})=26+8\sqrt{5}$$